# partner.soap.sforce.com Http POST request

Tags: soap-api, httprequest, partner-wsdl, httppost

What is the endpoint to POST

```
<env:Envelope
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> some content </env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't send the SOAP POST requests to **any** of those URLs. They are XML namespaces - see [Why are URLs in XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5758041/54026).

For the initial `login()` call you should use the endpoints defined in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm?search_text=login):

> "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/**version**/"

E.g. You need to replace "version" with the actual API version.  https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/49.0. You will typically see this endpoint address in the `<soap:address location>` at the end of the WSDL.

The LoginResult that gets returned from the `login()` API call will include a `serverURL`. All subsequent API requests need to go to that URL and include the sessionId in the header.